# socket connection command (socket = new Socket(addr,port)) thowing exception

Tags: android, sockets, exception, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to establish server-client connection using android app, where android app is client and linux pc is server, I am able to create sever on linux and it is connecting to client and sharing data.This linux pc is connected to the android hotspot.

What I am currently doing is, first I start hotspot using android app and wait till it connects to linux pc, once it is connected, linux pc creates server and wait for client where app waits for few secs after linux connected to hotspot (assuming few secs required to create server)  and then try to connect server.

I want my client to wait till it server is available at given addr and port, right now I am just assuming few secs delay and sending connection request to server. I tried using some looping method where it try to connect server for few times say 5. but it does not work.If I dont wait till server is created it throws exception, I have added try and catch method for this command . How to handle this ?

Comment: @greenapps sorry thats not android studio. Now I have edited the question.

Comment: `I am able to create sever on linux and it is connecting to client and sharing data.`. ??? Strange way of talking. Servers do not connect. It's the client that tries to connect to a server. Confusing talk at least. further its unclear about which client you are talking there.

Comment: `and wait till it connects to linux pc,`. No. One does not say so. The linux pc connects to the hotspot.

Comment: `If I dont wait till server is created it throws exception, ` Ok. But what does it matter? Just catch the exception and try again after some seconds. That is all you have to implement. A tiny loop untill connection established.

Comment: @greenapps I apologize for confusing sentences `linux pc connects to hotspot` and `client isconnecting to server and sharing data`.

Comment: And I talking about android app which is  used as client  `android app is client`

Comment: I am catching exception and ` I tried using some looping method where it try to connect server for few times say 5.` but this didnt work.

Comment: now I resolved this issue. Thank you